# Python Programming: 15 is displayed as an even number and the last number in the range is not considered

Tags: python

Python Programming: 15 is displayed as an even number and the last number in the range is not considered in the below program. I am new to programming , apologize if there is a blunder :-)

My Program:

```
for num in range (10,20):
    for i in range (2,num):
     if num%i == 0:
        print('%d is an even number' %(num))
        break
    else:
      print (num, 'is an odd number')
```

Result:  15 is displayed as an even number and 20 is not considered which is provided in the range.

```
10 is an even number
11 is an odd number
12 is an even number
13 is an odd number
14 is an even number
15 is an even number
16 is an even number
17 is an odd number
18 is an even number
19 is an odd number
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation?

Comment: What is your exact criteria for even number checking in this problem? If it is just checking whether a number is even, then you should just do `num % 2 == 0` for your check.

Comment: Er, aren't you checking whether a number is _prime_, not even? Replace "even" and "odd" with "composite" and "prime", and your output is factually correct.

Comment: The problem here is indentation - in Python the beginnings and ends of loops, ifs and other code sections are separated by a certain indent. In your code `else` is on the level of `for` nor `if`. Also, always use 4 spaces or 1 tab as an indent.

Comment: 20 is not part of this range. range(20) ends at 19 (range is 0-based).

Comment: If you wanted to know if a number is __even__, you would just test `%2`. You wouldn't loop through and check other factors. You're checking for other factors, which suggests that you're trying to find primes.

Comment: Hi Idjaw - I wanted to check a range of numbers and then want to print whether the number is an even or odd number. 10 to 20 is the range and 15 is displayed as even number in the result

Comment: @Tommy As mentioned by other people as well, if you are checking for even numbers then you only need to take the `% 2` result against the number. What you currently are doing is, again as others suggested, looks like you are checking for primes instead.

Comment: Thanks Idjaw, understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Range works like (start, end-1). so if you want upto `20`, you have to write `range(10,21)`

I think you want to check whether given number is even or odd.

below is the code

```
for num in range (10,21):
    if num%2 == 0:
        print (num,'is an even number')
    else:
        print (num, 'is an odd number')
```

Answer (score 0):

`15%3==0` - this is your problem. It should not be `num%i`, it should be `num%2`

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you run your program in a python console:

```
    In [1]: for num in range (10,20):
   ...:     for i in range (2,num):
   ...:         if num%i == 0:
   ...:             print('%d is an even number' %(num))
   ...:             break
   ...:         else:
   ...:             print (num, 'is an odd number')
   ...:             
10 is an even number
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
(11, 'is an odd number')
12 is an even number
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
(13, 'is an odd number')
14 is an even number
(15, 'is an odd number')
15 is an even number
16 is an even number
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
(17, 'is an odd number')
18 is an even number
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
(19, 'is an odd number')
```

Why? because you have a loop in a loop and you are doing:

```
In [2]: range(2, num) # given num == 10:
Out[2]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Implying that you will have situations like 15%3:

```
In [3]: 15%3
Out[3]: 0
```

Comment: Thank You Federico